# override a value in async function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-asyncio

I have this function in `my_module.py`:

```py
async def foo():
    a = 10
    b = 10
    return a+b
```

I am trying to override the value of `a` in `unittesting` using `aiohttp.test_utils.AioHTTPTestCase` and `@patch` decorator with `return_value=5` argument.
How to do this?

Comment: In what context would you need to unittest a hard-coded variable taking a different value?

Comment: This is a simpler example of the case I am facing. The actual case is a `pipeline` value

Comment: You can't patch local variables, only global variables and attributes of objects you can get a  reference to.